# Threejs raycaster is not working as intended

Tags: three.js

Thank you for reading. I'm creating my web site, but I have a problem.

[image]

Raycaster were working without hit.

```
const getRaycaster = () =>{
    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children)
    // raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)
    const rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector3(- 3, 0, 0)
    const rayDirection = new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0)
    rayDirection.normalize()
    
    raycaster.set(rayOrigin, rayDirection)
    scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0x00ff00) );

    if(intersects.length > 0) {
      intersects.forEach((intersect) =>{
        intersect.object.material.color.set(0x0450fb)
      })
    }
}   //getRaycaster end
```

```
createMesh(contactBox, scene, contactState, OBB) {
        this.contactBox = contactBox;
        this.OBB = OBB;
        this.scene = scene;
        this.contactState = contactState;

        for(let i = 0; i < contactBox.number; i++) {
            const mesh = this.contactBox.box[i];
            this.contactBox.group[i].add(mesh);
            mesh.name = this.contactBox.json[i][0]
            mesh.updateMatrixWorld();

            mesh.position.set(i, i, 0)
            this.scene.add(mesh)
        }
        return this.contactBox.group
}    //createMesh
```

Why is raycaster working more than range?

It's not only changed mesh on arrowhelper.

Sorry I can't write English very well. But I need your help, please.

Raycaster is working with arrowhelper.

Comment: Two things: you need to call `raycaster.intersectObjects` _after_ you set the origin and direction, and secondly, the raycasters direction isn't a vector with a length, it's normalised (if not weird things might happen). You set how `far` or `near` the intersecting happens by setting those properties on the raycaster. A `Ray` (used internally by the caster) has an infinite length, starts somewhere and points in a normalised direction. So: `rayDirection = new Vector3(1,0,0).normalize()`, and add `raycaster.far = 10` (or distance between two points), _then_ call `raycaster.intersectObjects`.

Comment: Thanks your kind.
It's not raycaster problem.
When i use the normal boxgeometry, it's working well. So i guess it's a lineSegments specificity.

Comment: Can you revise your question title to be more specific than “not working as intended”?

Comment: Try changing `raycaster.params.Line.threshold`. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.params